# There is no Global Planner on Turtlebot3 Navigation Package

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, base-global-planner, turtlebot3, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i install ros melodic and the turtlebot3 package with the procedure on this link : http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/pc_setup/#install-ubuntu-on-remote-pc

Then i want to edit the package for navigation, i want to change the method of global_planner from `navfn` to `CarrotPlanner` or `GlobalPlanner`. But when i edit the `move_base.launch` there is no `base_global_planner`, just`local_global_planner`.
And the parameter on the param folder, there is no `base_global_planner_params`, just `local_global_planner_params`.

1. Why there is no `base_global_planner` on the launch and params file on the turtlebot3 ?
2. If i added it manually the params and edit the launch file on the turtlebot3 package, will it works?
3. Give me recommendation the full robot package for learning. (That there's no additional file that i must added it like `base_global_planner` on turtlebot3 package)

Thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347371/there-is-no-global-planner-on-turtlebot3-navigation-package/) by [billynugrahas](https://answers.ros.org/users/48876/billynugrahas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2020-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default is equivalent to

```
<param name="base_global_planner" value="navfn/NavfnROS" />
```

Add this line as an parameter to move_base in move_base.launch and change the value to your desired global planner.
E.g.

```
<param name="base_global_planner" value="global_planner/GlobalPlanner" />
```

---

Originally posted by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) with karma: 525 on 2020-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billynugrahas](https://answers.ros.org/users/48876/billynugrahas/) on 2020-03-24**:
Thank you so much it helps me.
But i have some doubt, If i want to set the `parameter` of `base_global_planner`, where i can edit it ?
e.g. I want to use `A*` instead of `Dijkstra's Algorithm`. On this http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner mention that change the value of `use_dijkstra` to `False`.
Where i can edit it?

**Comment by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) on 2020-03-24**:
You should be able to put it just copy paste this on the row after you set the param for base_global_planner. I didn't try this explicitly:

```
<param name="GlobalPlanner/use_dijkstra" value="false"/>
```

Another option is to load yaml files for parameters but there are plenty of examples for that. See e.g the husky_navigation package.